# How to use multiple database in MVC without Entityframework? Based on user id only one database enable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my MVC application web config file has three or multiple sql database connection strings with different database. My question is based user login enable one database rest of two should be disable. Is this possible in Mvc without using Entity framework???

My web config file is,

```
<add key="SqlConnection" value="Data Source=10.10.9.89;Initial Catalog=ABC;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Pass1234"/>
   <add key="SqlConnection2" value="Data Source=10.10.9.89;Initial Catalog=XYZ;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Pass1234"/>
   <add key="SqlConnection3" value="Data Source=10.10.9.89;Initial Catalog=PQR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=Pass1234"/>
```

I have try this code,

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(LoginDetails log)
        {
            if (log.UserId == "Admin")
            {
               SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection"].ConnectionString);

            }
            else if (log.UserId == "Customer")
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection1"].ConnectionString);
            }
            else
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlConnection2"].ConnectionString);
            }
            return View();            
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if there are multiple connection string in the web.config, it depends on with which connection string the `SqlConnection` object is initialized.

Suppose there are three connection string, `myConnectionString1`, `myConnectionString2` and `myConnectionString3` in web.config, and you want to use second one, then -

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
 WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString2"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: If admin login myConnectionString1 need to enable rest of two connection string should be disable and  if user login myConnectionString2 is enable and rest of two is disable . Is correct??

Comment: @Parameswaran - All 3 connection string will be there in web.config file. It is just that when an admin logs in you initialize it with myConnectionString1  and if normal user logs in, you initialize it with myConnectionString2

Comment: I wrote the code based on condition it throw the error

Comment: @Parameswaran - Please edit your question, and show the code that you have written for it.